# Can Spring MVC inject Example<T> from spring-data into controller method invocation >

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Let's assume we have a `User` entity with `name` property and a REST API which provides querying of the user data with pagination, sorting and filter on entity fields.

Can Spring MVC inject `Example<User>` from **spring-data** into controller method invocation as it does with `Pageable` ?

If so. How to make it work ?

In code:

To implement `GET /bike?offset=20&name=Jo` request which returns paginable results of all users whose name starts with "Jo" I use:

```
  @GetMapping
    public Page<User> all(Pageable p, User u) {
        Example<User> ex = Example.of(u, startMatcher);
        return repo.findAll(ex, p);
    }
```

This contains unnecessary boilerplate.

Can I somehow achieve:

```
  @GetMapping
    public Page<Bike> all(Pageable p, Example<Bike> b) {
        return repo.findAll(ex, p);
    }
```

with custom set default `ExampleMatcher` ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with custom web binding.

#### Resolver

```
public class FilterArgResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    ExampleMatcher startMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.STARTING);

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter param) {
        return param.getParameterAnnotation(Filter.class) != null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter param,
                                  @Nullable ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  @Nullable WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

        Class clazz = param.getParameterAnnotation(Filter.class).value();

        Object o = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();

        ServletRequestDataBinder b = (ServletRequestDataBinder) binderFactory.
                createBinder(webRequest, o, "filter");
        b.bind((ServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest());
        BindingResult r = b.getBindingResult();
        Object t = r.getTarget();
        return Example.of(t, startMatcher);
    }
}
```

#### Registration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new FilterArgResolver());
    }

}
```

#### Custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Filter {

    Class<?> value();
}
```

#### Usage

```
  @GetMapping
    public Page<Bike> all(Pageable p, @Filter(Bike.class) Example<Bike> ex) {
        return repo.findAll(ex, p);
    }
```